# Error while i try to get PrivateKey.getEncode

Tags: java, android, rsa

I have this code

```
RSAPrivateKeySpec privateSpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(modulus, privateExponent);
KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey priv = factory.generatePrivate(privateSpec);
byte[] tmp = priv.getEncode();
```

And i get error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

In my app i demonstrate RSA algorithm with showing up private key and public key. I don't have any problem with getting publickey's encode, but when i try to get privatekey's encode i get this error

```
  public BigInteger getCoprime(BigInteger m, SecureRandom random) {
        int length = m.bitLength()-1;
        BigInteger e = BigInteger.probablePrime(length,random);
        while (! (m.gcd(e)).equals(BigInteger.ONE) ) {
            e = BigInteger.probablePrime(length,random);
        }
        return e;
    }
    private void Generate()throws
            NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidKeyException,
            NoSuchPaddingException,
            IllegalBlockSizeException,
            BadPaddingException,
            InvalidKeySpecException{
        int keySize = 512;
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        BigInteger p = BigInteger.probablePrime(keySize/2, random);
        BigInteger q = BigInteger.probablePrime(keySize/2,random);
        BigInteger modulus = p.multiply(q);
        BigInteger m = (p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
        BigInteger publicExponent = getCoprime(m,random);
        BigInteger privateExponent = publicExponent.modInverse(m);
        RSAPublicKeySpec spec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, publicExponent);
        RSAPrivateKeySpec privateSpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(modulus, privateExponent);
        KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey pub = factory.generatePublic(spec);
        PrivateKey priv = factory.generatePrivate(privateSpec);
        EditText privateKey = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPrivateKeyy);
        EditText publicKey = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPublicKeyy);
        publicKey.setText(Hex.toHexString(pub.getEncoded()));
    }
```

This is my method to show keys

Comment: Information provided is not sufficient to troubleshoot. You should consider posting stack trace so folks can help you.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.